# Inicio de sesin con email y usuario da error

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Hola tengo este codigo que me valida el usuario o email, dependiendo cual elija, pero quisiera poder usar cualquiera de los 2:

```php
        private function get_user_hash($username){

        try {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password, username, memberID FROM members WHERE email = :username AND active="Yes" ');
            $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

            return $stmt->fetch();

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }
```

ahi valida el email, en cambio si hago asi:

```
$stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password, username, memberID FROM members WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" ');
```

me valida el usuario...intenté esto para poder usar cualquiera de los 2:

```
    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password, username, memberID FROM members WHERE (email = :username OR username = :username) AND active="Yes" ');
```

y no hay caso me da este error:

```
    SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diria que el problema es este, explicado en la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) del `prepare`:

> Se debe incluir un único marcador de parámetro para cada valor que se
> desee pasar a la sentencia cuando se llame a PDOStatement::execute().
> No se puede usar un marcador de parámetro con nombre con el mismo
> nombre más de una vez en una sentencia preparada, a menos que el modo
> de emulación esté activado.

Por lo tanto prueba esto:

```php
private function get_user_hash($username){
    try {
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password, username, memberID FROM members WHERE (email = :email OR username = :username) AND active="Yes" ');        
        $stmt->execute(array(
            'username'  => $username,
            'email'     => $username
        ));

        return $stmt->fetch();

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    }
}
```

y nos cuentas a ver que tal.

Comment: Hola masterguru, groso mall...funciono perfecto, como envidio (bien no) poder alcanzar algún día ese conocimiento para resolver estas cuestiones y poder programar o llevar a un programa, lo que se me haya ocurrido...lamentablemente yo me valgo de lo que encuentro en internet y lo voy modificando adaptando a mis necesidades, siempre con la ayuda de internet también para eso, hasta que me encuentro en algún callejón sin salida para mi como este, y debo consultar...muchas gracias realmente, funciona genial, saludos...

Comment: Bueno, tampoco es para tanto, lo he resuelto como siempre, un poco de experiencia y saber buscar las cosas y leerme la documentación de cada caso concreto :-)  Si la respuesta satisface tu pregunta deberias marcarla como aceptada para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede pendiente eternamente. Para aprender a aceptar respuestas puedes visitar este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200). Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Hola @Landom yo la consulta la haría de esta manera,

```
'SELECT password, username, memberID FROM members WHERE active="Yes" AND email = :username OR username = :username'
```

Sin los parentesis te funcionara, también pongo el active primero porque se ve mejor que el **OR** es una condición de esto o esto. Espero que te funcione

Comment: Hola Jordi Turell, ya lo había probado y no funciona, con y sin parentesis...la solución la aporto masterguru, anda genial, gracias igual por tomarte el trabajo de responderme..

Comment: Perfecto me alegro que te haya funcionado gracias a @masterguru, acéptale la respuesta. Como la correcta. :)